# Show that $a_n= \sqrt{x+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}}$ Converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Show that $a_n= \sqrt{x+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}}, a_1=\sqrt{x}$ Converges.
>   *) $x>1$

I tried to show that $a_n$ is monotone and bounded but failed showing it algebraically.

I'd be glad for help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try induction: suppose that $a_n\geq a_{n-1}$ then
$$
  a_{n+1} = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{a_n}} \geq \sqrt{x + \sqrt{a_{n-1}}} = a_n.
$$
I assume that $a_2\geq a_1$ is not hard to show.

To show boundness, first consider the case $x \geq 2$. Assume that $a_n\leq \sqrt{2x}$, then 
$$
  a_{n+1} = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{a_n}} \leq \sqrt{x+\sqrt[4]{2x}}\leq\sqrt{x+x} = \sqrt{2x},
$$
hence the sequence is bounded for $x\geq 2$. Notice also that $a_n(x)\leq a_n(x')$ if $x\leq x'$, so that the boundness holds for all $x\geq 0$.

Comment: Thank you, what about boundedness?

Comment: @AlonAlon: which bounds are you talking about?

Comment: $a_n$ needs to be bounded by some $M>0$ so we can say the series converges.

Comment: I've added that $x>1$.

Comment: @AlonAlon: edited, please tell me whether anything is unclear. It's also a good tone not to accept answers until you are sure you want see them accepted (and hence do not dis-accept them later). Just consider this in future.